# Undefined variable Wordpress Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having a hard time trying to get a shortcode working for my WP theme. I keep getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: output in ........\wp-content\plugins\sunland-shortcodesV2\includes\shortcode-functions.php on line 119

Here is the code for the shortcode that I'm creating.

```
if( !function_exists('bizbox_shortcode') ) {
function bizbox_shortcode($atts, $content = NULL) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "image" => '',
    "description" => '',
    "title" => 'Business Name',
    "address" => '123 Main St. Chula Vista Ca.',
    "phone" => '(619)555-1234',
   ), $atts) );

$output .= '<div class="bizbox clearfix">';
if ( $image ) { $output .= '<div class="bizthumb"><img src="'. $image .'" alt="Visit our friends close by" /></div>'; }
$output .= '<div class="bizdesc">';
$output .= '<h2>'. $title .'</h2>';
$output .= ''. $address .' <br />';
$output .= $phone;
if ( $description ) { $output .= '<p>'. $description .'</p>'; }
$output .= '</div></div>';
return $output;
}}
add_shortcode('bizbox', 'bizbox_shortcode');
```

Line 119 would be the first $output line. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your first output should be `$output =` (no dot), because before that $output does not exist and so you can't add to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the . before the `$output` variable the first time it appears. 
Rewrite as

```
$output = '<div class="bizbox clearfix">';
if ( $image ) { 
 $output .= '<div class="bizthumb"><img src="'. $image     .'" alt="Visit our friends close by" /></div>'; }
 $output .= '<div class="bizdesc">';
 $output .= '<h2>'. $title .'</h2>';
 $output .= ''. $address .' <br />';
 $output .= $phone;
 if ( $description ) { $output .= '<p>'. $description .'</p>'; }
 $output .= '</div></div>';
return $output;
```

`

Comment: THANKS!! I was totally missing that.